# Get <T> class - possible?

Tags: java

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class DmValue<T>
```

And many classes extends it, for example:

```
class DmBoolean extends DmValue<Boolean>

class DmText extends DmValue<String>

class DmDate extends DmValue<Date>
```

My question is how to find T class?

I need to write a static function:

```
static Class getT(Class<? extends DmValue> valueClass){...}
```

In case of valueClass = DmText.class, getT function should return String.class

In case of valueClass = DmBoolean.class, getT function should return Boolean.class

Any suggestions?

Comment: The <T> type in Java is a construct that only exists up to the compile time and is not available in the executable/byte code. Thus it is impossible to determine a Class<T> object at runtime.

Comment: make Class<T> a field and pass the concrete class to the abstract's constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `Class<T>` in your constructors,

```
abstract class DmValue<T> {
    Class<T> cls;
    public DmValue(Class<T> cls) {
        this.cls = cls;
    }
    public Class<T> getValueType() {
        return this.cls;
    }
}
```

Then initialize it in your subclasses, like

```
class DmBoolean extends DmValue<Boolean> {
    public DmBoolean() {
        super(Boolean.class);
    }
}
```

Then you can access it by calling `getValueType()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can grab generic interfaces of a class by Class#getGenericInterfaces() which you then in turn check if it's a ParameterizedType and then grab the actual type arguments accordingly.

Type[] genericInterfaces = BarFoo.class.getGenericInterfaces();
for (Type genericInterface : genericInterfaces) {
    if (genericInterface instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        Type[] genericTypes = ((ParameterizedType) genericInterface).getActualTypeArguments();
        for (Type genericType : genericTypes) {
            System.out.println("Generic type: " + genericType);
        }
    }
}
```